# R: while and if-else loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a loop for the following example dataset (df1):

| id | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 48795 |
| 2 | 134555 |
| 3 | 91956 |
| 4 | 112125 |
| 5 | 2241 |
| 6 | 6325 |
| 7 | 23660 |
| 8 | 393 |
| 9 | 3687 |

First, I want to calculate a new value X for every row with equation: X = 5*A/summation(all A values)

Second, I want to determine if there is any X value >= 1. If so, store those rows to a new data frame, df2.

Third, I want to removed the selected rows in step 2, and repeat the first and second step with the rest of the rows in df1, until all Xs are smaller than 1.

My expected result would be like: (I just put random numbers in X)

| id | A | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 48795 | 1.052 |
| 2 | 134555 | 3.265 |
| 3 | 91956 | 2.36 |
| 4 | 112125 | 4.25 |

And here is what I've tried:

```
df2 = data.frame(id = numeric(),
                 A = numeric()
                 x = numeric())

df1$pi =(5*df1$A/sum(df1$A))

while(df1$X >= 1)
{
  df2 = rbind(df2, df1[df1$X >= 1,])
  subset(df1, X >= 1)
  df1$X =(5*df1$A/sum(df1$A))
}
```

Warning in while (q2.df$pi >= 1) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

And based on the warning message, I tried the code below (just a little switch):

```
df2 = data.frame(id = numeric(),
                 A = numeric()
                 x = numeric())

while(df1$X >= 1)
{
  df1$X =(5*df1$A/sum(df1$A))
  df2 = rbind(df2, df1[df1$X >= 1,])
  subset(df1, X >= 1)

}
```

Then it shows that argument is of length zero.
And that also leads to my question about loop: when should I start the loop (like in this problem, should I set up the X column before or after I start the while loop?)

It's my first time to write a loop, so regret if there are stupid mistakes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: For subsetting, you may do `subset(df1, X >=1)`

Comment: You have an unclosed `(` in the line that starts with `df1$pi`

Comment: Do you also want to store the `X` or is it just used to see if the condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

With the example data set `df2` will still be empty but here is the `while` loop corrected.

```
df2 = data.frame(id = numeric(),
                 A = numeric(),
                 X = numeric())

df1$X <- df1$A/sum(df1$A)
while(any(X >= 1)){
  df2 <- rbind(df2, df1[df1$X >= 1, ])
  df1 <- df1[df1$X < 1, ]
  df1$X <- 5*df1$A/sum(df1$A)
}
```

---

### Test data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
id  A
1   48795
2   134555
3   91956
4   112125
5   2241
6   6325
7   23660
8   393
9   3687
", header = TRUE)
```